# python logging set loglevel for all subloggers of one module

Tags: python, python-logging

How can I easily set all `urllib3.*` subbloggers without having to explicitly set each one or filter.

I believed `urllib3` would set it and its subloggers but:

```py
loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
for name in loggers:
  if args.debug:
    name.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
  else:
    name.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logging.getLogger('urllib3').setLevel(logging.WARN) # only set root not subloggers
print(loggers)
#[ <Logger urllib3.util.retry (DEBUG)>, 
#  <Logger urllib3.util (DEBUG)>, 
#  <Logger urllib3 (WARNING)>,
#  <Logger urllib3.connection (DEBUG)>,
#  <Logger urllib3.response (DEBUG)>,
#  <Logger urllib3.connectionpool (DEBUG)>,
#  <Logger urllib3.poolmanager (DEBUG)>,
#  :
```

My current workaround is to start all my modules logging-name with `root.`, and explicitly set everything else to `logging.WARN`, then I get the root-logger also, but not very flexible in naming:

```py
loggers = [logging.getLogger(name) for name in logging.root.manager.loggerDict]
for name in loggers:
  if not re.search(r'^<Logger\sroot', str(name)):
    name.setLevel(logging.WARN)
  else:
    if args.debug:
      name.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    else:
      name.setLevel(logging.INFO)
print(loggers)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
import logging


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.INFO)
    print(logging.getLogger("urllib3"))
    print(logging.getLogger("urllib3.util.retry"))
    logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    print(logging.getLogger("urllib3"))
    print(logging.getLogger("urllib3.util.retry"))
```

This outputs the following:

```
<Logger urllib3 (INFO)>
<Logger urllib3.util.retry (INFO)>
<Logger urllib3 (ERROR)>
<Logger urllib3.util.retry (ERROR)>
```

Modifying `logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.ERROR)` to `logging.getLogger("urllib3.util").setLevel(logging.ERROR)` outputs the following:

```
<Logger urllib3 (INFO)>
<Logger urllib3.util.retry (INFO)>
<Logger urllib3 (INFO)>
<Logger urllib3.util.retry (ERROR)>
```

Additionally, if more precise handling is necessary, according to [logging's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel), if a child logger has level `logging.NOTSET` (as it is defined by default), then `logging` proceeds to "delegate to the parent", meaning that it will look through the parents and take the first level different than `logging.NOTSET`. It seems the `urllib3` loggers are set to `logging.WARN` by default, but setting them to `logging.NOTSET` initially should allow you to manipulate their levels more easily down the road.

Comment: The clue was the `logging.NOTSET` my fiddling changed all the `logging.NOTSET` in subloggers so they could not be controlled from the parent.